# How do I search a file for a string then use it as a variable?

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, grep

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<id>456</id>

<root>
<value>1</value>
<intNum>2</intNum>
</root>

<root>
<eulav>1</eulav>
<muNtni>2</muNtni>
</root>
```

I want to remember `<id>456</id>` and then do this:

```
sed 's/\<root\>/\
\<root\> 
$herecomestheid
```

Basically what this does is replace `<root>` with `<root>\n<id>456</id>`. `\n` in this case means newline. I already know that, but the problem I'm having is remembering `<id>456</id>` and keep it ready for usage later.

I tried this (which quite obviously didn't work):

```
 sed -i '' 's/\<root\>/\
 \<root\>\
 \<id\>.\<\/id\>/g'
```

and I tried to do something like this:

```
cat file.xml | grep '\<id\>*\<\/id\>'
```

And tried making the grepped output into a variable. And that obviously didn't work either.

EDIT:  `<id>*</id>` is supposed to be under root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processing XML as text is generally not a robust solution, but if you insist on doing it then you could perhaps make use of sed's *hold space*  e.g.

```
sed -e '/<id>[0-9]*<\/id>/h' -e '/<root>/{x;p;x;}' file.xml
```

Comment: Yeah, do you have any ideas how i would do it any other way? `xmlstarlet` is confusing.

Comment: I've played with python's [minidom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) parser but I don't know enough to recommend it

Comment: This placed `<id>*</id>` above `<root>`, its supposed to place it under `<root>`. And thats my fault, there was a typo in the question.

Comment: @DisplayName - it placed it above only because you didn't `p`rint `<root>` first. `<root>` would be autoprinted at the end of the script, whereas `<id>` is explicitly `p`rinted here *during* the script. Also, this probably prints `<id>` twice, yeah? You need to `d`elete it from output when you `h`old it, too.

Comment: I really don't understand, how would i "print" root first?

Comment: If you want to print the matched string `<root>` *first* that's arguably simpler: `sed -e '/<id>[0-9]*<\/id>/h' -e '/<root>/G' file.xml` (the `G` command appends the contents of the hold space to that of the pattern space)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e :b -e '$!{N;\|<id>.*\n<root>|!bb
};do what ever you want to do with all of those lines now....'
```

I agree with steeldriver that `h`oldspace is probably the best bet, but there are other options. Sometimes we can't be bothered to manage both buffers - or, and as is often my problem - we already *are* managing both buffers. The above snippet stacks lines in pattern space. As long as  always occurs between `<id>` tags it will always recursively fill pattern space with the data block you want before moving on to line 2 - *that is, it will do it so long as the buffers don't implode in the meantime - but that's a rather hard thing to do nowadays*.

Also, back to the `h`old space thing, e`x`change really does *swap* `h`old and pattern space. Using it once renders the pattern buffer as the `h`old buffer and vice versa. This effect survives line cycles. Often what I do is read in a file until I reach a starter line, perform preliminary edits, then swap and keep `H`olding until I get another. When my script swaps back it winds up a block behind - at the last marker I switched on, plus everything `H`eld in the meantime. It's a simple way to buffer only as much as necessary when you must.

And so, another way to implement a loop like you wish to do is:

```
sed -e '/<id>/h;//!H;/<root>/!{$!d' -e '};x...'
```

From that point on your pattern space is `H`old space and vice versa. `h`old will *overwrite* `h`old space with the current pattern space whenever it is used - so the above example starts a fresh buffer with an `<id>` line every time. `!H` *appends* all intervening lines to `H`old space each following a `\n`ewline character. `$!d`eletes pattern space on every line that is `!`not the `$`last once the current line is safely `H`eld and begins the next line cycle, and so e`x`change only occurs on `<root>` matches by which time the whole block is waiting for you.

Just bear in mind that on your *very last* block, your marker is probably the last line, in case it differs from the `<root>` matches.

***But...***

According to your edit, I don't see any reason you couldn't get away with:

```
sed '/<id>/h;//d;\|</root>|G
' <<\INPUT
unimportant 1
<id> number 1 </id>
<root> sub text
more text
 more text
</root>
<root> sub text as well
and more text
and more text
</root>
unimportant 2
<id> number 2 </id>
<root> sub text
more text
more text
</root>
<root> sub text
and more text
and more text
</root>
INPUT
```

There `<id>` lines are `h`eld *(again: overwriting `h`old space)* then `d`eleted from output. When a `</root>` match occurs, `sed` `G`ets the `h`old space appended to pattern space before auto-printing the results at line-cycle's end which looks like:

```
unimportant 1
<root> sub text 
more text
 more text
</root>
<id> number 1 </id>
<root> sub text as well
and more text
and more text
</root>
<id> number 1 </id>
unimportant 2
<root> sub text
more text
more text
</root>
<id> number 2 </id>
<root> sub text
and more text
and more text
</root>
<id> number 2 </id>
```

Comment: @Displayname - I updated this according to your edit.

Comment: What am i supposed to run?

Comment: @DisplayName - I think you mean, which one? Do `sed '/<id>/h;//d;\|</root>|G' <infile` and have a look at the results. Feel free to ask here in the comments of course if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `awk` would be

```
awk '/<id>/{id=$0}/<root>/{print id}1' file.xml
```

If you do not want to print the `<id>` line you can skip that line by adding `next`.

```
awk '/<id>/{id=$0;next}/<root>/{print id}1' file.xml
```